# How to transfer FFmpeg's AVPacket to CUVID's CUVIDSOURCEDATAPACKET? or how to use FFmpeg's CUVID,any demo?

Tags: ffmpeg, cuda

As the title said,I was trapped to *How to transfer FFmpeg's AVPacket to CUVID's CUVIDSOURCEDATAPACKET*,and my main code about this question is below:`

```
AVPacket* avpkt;
avpkt = (AVPacket*)av_malloc(sizeof(AVPacket));
CUVIDSOURCEDATAPACKET cupkt;
int iPkt = 0;
while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, avpkt) >= 0) {
    if (avpkt->stream_index == videoindex) {

        cuCtxPushCurrent(g_oContext);

        if (avpkt && avpkt->size) {
            cupkt.payload_size = (unsigned long)avpkt->size;
            cupkt.payload = (const unsigned char*)avpkt->data;

            if (avpkt->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
                cupkt.flags = CUVID_PKT_TIMESTAMP;
                if (pCodecCtx->pkt_timebase.num && pCodecCtx->pkt_timebase.den) {
                    AVRational tb;
                    tb.num = 1;
                    tb.den = AV_TIME_BASE;
                    cupkt.timestamp = av_rescale_q(avpkt->pts, pCodecCtx->pkt_timebase, tb);
                }
                else
                    cupkt.timestamp = avpkt->pts;
            }
        }
        else {
            cupkt.flags = CUVID_PKT_ENDOFSTREAM;
        }

        oResult = cuvidParseVideoData(hParser_, &cupkt);
        if ((cupkt.flags & CUVID_PKT_ENDOFSTREAM) || (oResult != CUDA_SUCCESS)) {
            break;
        }
        iPkt++;
        printf("Succeed to read avpkt %d !\n", iPkt);
        checkCudaErrors(cuCtxPopCurrent(NULL));
    }
    av_free_packet(avpkt);
}
```

and as you see,the code

```
cupkt.payload_size = (unsigned long)avpkt->size;
cupkt.payload = (const unsigned char*)avpkt->data;
```

needs to be corrected。
I'm poor at english,I hope I have expressed my self clearly。

Comment: Or how to use FFmpeg's CUVID ,because I know FFmpeg has already implemented cuvid,but i dont know how to code it ,do you have a example of it ? or some releated documents are also welcomed.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very happy today.Last night after I asked this question,I went to look through the source code of FFmpeg,after a few hours of hardwork ,I found a little difference between my code ande FFmpeg's.So I will anwser this question myself.

```
AVBitStreamFilterContext* h264bsfc = NULL;
if (pCodecCtx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264 || pCodecCtx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_HEVC) {
    if (pCodecCtx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
        h264bsfc = av_bitstream_filter_init("h264_mp4toannexb");
    else
        h264bsfc = av_bitstream_filter_init("hevc_mp4toannexb");
}

AVPacket *avpkt;
avpkt = (AVPacket *)av_malloc(sizeof(AVPacket));
CUVIDSOURCEDATAPACKET cupkt;
int iPkt = 0;
while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, avpkt) >= 0){
    if (avpkt->stream_index == videoindex){

        cuCtxPushCurrent(g_oContext);

        if (avpkt && avpkt->size) {
            if (h264bsfc)
            {
                av_bitstream_filter_filter(h264bsfc, pFormatCtx->streams[videoindex]->codec, NULL, &avpkt->data, &avpkt->size, avpkt->data, avpkt->size, 0);
            }

            cupkt.payload_size = (unsigned long)avpkt->size;
            cupkt.payload = (const unsigned char*)avpkt->data;

            if (avpkt->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
                cupkt.flags = CUVID_PKT_TIMESTAMP;
                if (pCodecCtx->pkt_timebase.num && pCodecCtx->pkt_timebase.den){
                    AVRational tb;
                    tb.num = 1;
                    tb.den = AV_TIME_BASE;
                    cupkt.timestamp = av_rescale_q(avpkt->pts, pCodecCtx->pkt_timebase, tb);
                }
                else
                    cupkt.timestamp = avpkt->pts;
            }
        }
        else {
            cupkt.flags = CUVID_PKT_ENDOFSTREAM;
        }

        oResult = cuvidParseVideoData(hParser_, &cupkt);
        if ((cupkt.flags & CUVID_PKT_ENDOFSTREAM) || (oResult != CUDA_SUCCESS)){
            break;
        }
        iPkt++;
        //printf("Succeed to read avpkt %d !\n", iPkt);
        checkCudaErrors(cuCtxPopCurrent(NULL));
    }
    av_free_packet(avpkt);
}

if (h264bsfc)
{
    av_bitstream_filter_close(h264bsfc);
}
```

the main difference is below:

```
AVBitStreamFilterContext* h264bsfc = NULL;
if (pCodecCtx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264 || pCodecCtx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_HEVC) {
    if (pCodecCtx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
        h264bsfc = av_bitstream_filter_init("h264_mp4toannexb");
    else
        h264bsfc = av_bitstream_filter_init("hevc_mp4toannexb");
}
········
if (h264bsfc)
{
    av_bitstream_filter_filter(h264bsfc, pFormatCtx->streams[videoindex]->codec, NULL, &avpkt->data, &avpkt->size, avpkt->data, avpkt->size, 0);
}
·········
if (h264bsfc)
{
    av_bitstream_filter_close(h264bsfc);
}
```

this is because the file I use is H264 format,there is something must be done with NALU of H264(I don't know what is it,I got it from anwsers of another people's question,and I haven't know it clearly,maybe the problem is not like what I said).The code I add works for me,and I hope my anwser coulde help you.As I memtioned,I'm poor at English,if you are confused about what I said,just go to the code.